# Ruby on Rails - Having issues trying to connect to a mysql2 database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, dotcloud

**Basic Information**

I have a rails app **A** that is connected to a mysql database hosted on dotcloud.com. Below is how my database.yml file looks like,

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: <host>
  port: <port>
  database: <database_name>
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
```

Until here it works fine, I can access the records in the database from **A**, do queries and stuff.

Now I have another rails app **B** that needs to be connected to the same database as **A**, so i simply copy and paste the exact same details above into the database.yml file in **B**. However, when I tried to go into the rails console on production, I can't seem to access the database. For example if I had a User Table, it will just say `NameError: uninitialized constant User`.

Is this an access control issue? How should I go about debugging this problem?

Appreciate any advice.

---

**Update**

So I copy and paste the .rb and schema files from **A** to **B**. However I am getting `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)` when trying to access the database in rails console. Anyone know how to ?

Comment: Are the applications hosted on the same server? If not it may be a difference in hostnames or mysql access. For instance using a host of localhost on the production machine indicates that the mysql server is on the same server. However copying connection details and using them on another server would connect you to a different database server if any.

Comment: I copied the connection details including those I mentioned above. So I guess, it should connect to the database i specified regardless of server? Both A and B are hosted on Dotcloud.

Comment: @JohnLee Are you getting your database credentials from environment.json or environment.yml when your application loads, or are you hard coding those values in your database.yml?

Comment: @JohnLee the issue is that the database host can look the same but machines still have the ability to redirect traffic to that host to particular IP addresses. Also traffic to the database may be restricted to only allow local connections which would mean you can only access it on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new rails app, and setup everything again. Copy the same database.yml config then did rake db:migrate, then include the necessary model files, went into rails console and it works now.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the migrations for app B? Of course, the database is already set up but App B doesn't have a copy of the schema. So, you can either run the migrations in App B or copy the schema from App A to App B.

Answer (score 0):

Try to list your tables using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

That should show if you can at least get to the database correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent debug tip! It helped me. I was using "ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('SHOW TABLES')", which was not catching an error since I upgraded to Rails 3.1.

Comment: Jason - glad I was able to help. If my answer contributed, an appropriate response would be an upvote if you feel it appropriate.